# Why doesn't this ImageButton's onClick fire in Android 2.3?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, imagebutton, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have verified that setOnClickListener is being called, so why doesn't the button click do anything in 2.3? It works fine in 4.1. I am testing on emulators with cameras emulated. I have tried making sure the button is clickable in xml, but that didn't do anything.

```
ImageButton mPhotoButton = null;
if (v != null) {
    mPhotoButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_imageButton);
}
if (mPhotoButton != null) {
    mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimeCameraActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PHOTO);
        }
    });
}
```

xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/crime_imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
```

setting button to disabled, why is this executing only in 2.3?:

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (pm != null) {
    if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) && !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        if (mPhotoButton != null) {
            mPhotoButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show where you have this code in fragment or activity?

Comment: Are you sure you're not drawing anything on top of it?

Comment: the only thing visible here seems that your if(mPhotoButton != null) is actually null so it never let it happen!

Comment: I'm guessing you are setting the listener in a fragment. If you say you are sure that you capture the click events, your problem is with startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PHOTO);

Comment: @Saqib it is probably not null because that way listener would not invoke click event.

Comment: do you mean your onClick event is triggering??? if so then what? doesn't code inside that work?

Comment: ok I have found the root of the problem, but I am still not sure why this only occurs in 2.3 emulator and not 4.1. I have added the section of code that causes the button to be disabled. Still not sure why it is being executed though.

Comment: ok it turns out, the button is disabled per the code above in all emulators running < 4.0. Apparently camera emulation not allowed pre api 14.